# How to get input type file generated dynamically, by it's name

Tags: asp.net

I generate file upload dynamically, but I can't get their value by name.
this is a input type file that generated dynamically:

```
<input class="inp_file" onchange="sub(this)" name="subopf_36_32" type="file">
```

and I used this code to get file upload, but it always return null:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Request.Form.Count; i++)
        {
    if (Request.Form.Keys[i].Contains("subopf"))
                {
                    HttpPostedFile file = Request.Files[Request.Form.Keys[i]];

                    if (file!=null && file.ContentLength > 0)
                    {
                        //some code
                    }
                }
}
```

Comment: Please check count of your requests like
int i = Request.Form.Keys[i].Contains("subopf").Count;
on i you get any value, Please update!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Files are in the `Request.Files` collection, not the `Request.Form` collection.

```
for( int i =0; i < Request.Files.Count; i++){
var file = Request.Files[i];
}
```

Your form needs an enctype attribute set to `"multipart/form-data"` to make file uploads work. It's added automatically when you use the asp: FileUpload control. You need to add it yourself when you add the file inputs dynamically.